# How do I copy or fill the image with color

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, editing, photoshop-cs5

How do I copy the colour from a to b. im using photoshop classic and i cant seem to get it right

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Use the clone tool (Ink stamp icon)

Comment: Thank you, that has worked

Comment: @xenoid please post this as an answer. Then OP can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the clone tool (Ink stamp icon)